# How do I test to see if an image file exists using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to generate a report that checks if the `@href` values actually reference an existing file. The `file:exists()` function is great for checking if an XML file exists. However, when the external file is an image e.g. jpg, png, etc... this function gives the error:

> Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@href]">
    <xsl:variable name="resPath" select="resolve-uri( @href, base-uri() )"/>        
    <xsl:variable name="check">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::image">
                <!-- do something here that results in a boolean value. file:exists() does not work for images-->
            
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- this works for xml files -->
                <xsl:value-of select="file:exists($resPath)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>            
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$check = true()">
            <li>                    
                <span><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></span><span style="padding-left:5px">Good</span>
            </li>                
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>                
            <li style="background-color:#ffcccc" >
                <span><xsl:value-of select="@href"/></span><span style="padding-left:5px">Bad</span>
            </li>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>        
</xsl:template>
```

I am using XSLT 2.0 and Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried a EE 9.8.0.12 with a `.jpg` file but don't get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing

```
<xsl:value-of select="file:exists($resPath)"/>
```

`file:exists()` returns a boolean, true or false. `<xsl:value-of>` turns that into a text node, "true" or "false".

You're putting the result in a document node constructed using

```
<xsl:variable name="check">
```

You then do:

```
<xsl:when test="$check = true()">
```

which compares a document node with a boolean. The result of doing this actually depends on whether your stylesheet specifies version="1.0" or version="2.0", which you haven't told us. Either way, it's probably not a happy outcome. More specifically:

- If version="1.0", the comparison of a node-set to the boolean value true returns true if the node-set is non-empty, which this one is; so your test $check=true() always returns true
- If version="2.0", the node-set is atomised, resulting in the untypedAtomic value "true" or "false", and this is then cast to a boolean `true()` or `false()`. So you might be lucky in this case: despite the convoluted series of type conversions, you might end up with the right answer.

Basic discipline for XSLT 2.0+:

- always declare the type of your variables and parameters with an "as" clause
- Use `xsl:sequence` rather than `xsl:value-of` unless you actually want to construct a text node

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The error was caused by the subsequent apply templates. Once that was fixed this solution worked perfect

Comment: Glad you found the error. The primary reason for putting an "as" attribute on all your `xsl:param` and `xsl:variable` declarations is that you will get much better diagnostics for errors.